# How to enable the jupyter_http_over_ws extension

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to connect Google Colab to a local runtime (Windows 10). As part of that I need to add the jupyter_http_over_ws extension to Jupyter Notebook. `py -m pip install jupyter_http_over_ws` worked as expected but when I tried to enable it with `py -m notebook serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws`, it errored.

`[E 13:43:13.400 NotebookApp] Support for specifying --pylab on the command line has been removed.`
`[E 13:43:13.400 NotebookApp] Please use %pylab jupyter_http_over_ws or %matplotlib jupyter_http_over_ws in the notebook itself.`

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the extention and try **pip3 install install jupyter_http_over_ws**. It worked fine for me.

Comment: My problem wasn't with the installation but rather with enabling it in Jupyter. Were you able to get the extension working without any issues?

Answer (score -1):

Run `jupyter-serverextension enable jupyter_http_over_ws`